# RedBeans and two ownLists of same bean type

Tags: redbean

I'd like to have something like this in a bean:

`ownWheelList` `ownSpareList`

Those two lists are of the same model type. Both hold `wheel`beans.

So while the first is good the second is not. This is clear, because RedBeans awaits beans of type `spare` which do not exists.

Is it possible to do something like aliasing on list like it is on objects?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see it working, when you use `ownList`, it means you'll find every registry that have a column named `mainbean_id` on each table (`wheel` and `spare`).

So if you want to differ wheel and spare you could use a `type` column such as `wheel = 1` AND `spare = 2`, then you can load the list using a `with` condition like `$mainbean->with("AND type = ?", [1])->ownWheelList` to get wheel list and `$mainbean->with("AND type = ?", [2])->ownWheelList` to get spare list.